# NetSuite Saved Search -- % of Total Summary

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

Not sure if this is possible in a saved search, but I want to run a calculation off the summed summary results and display it on the same line. I have a SUM of quantity column and a SUM of quantity fulfilled. I want another column that does qty fulfilled / qty as a percentage but it has to be calculated at the summary level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPN0M.jpg)

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur9t3.jpg)

Basically I want to do the following but based on the summary data only, in order to calculate the total fill rate (fulfilled/qty ordered) rather than an average fill rate per order. I don't know if it's possible in a summary saved search.(NVL({quantitycommitted},0)+NVL({quantityshiprecv},0))/NULLIF({quantity},0)

With the above and with the AVERAGE function, it's giving me the average of the individual order fill rates. I want the aggregate fill rate instead. If there are 10 orders and 9 filled at 90%, 1 at 0%, my current formula gives me 90%. But what if that 1 order had a way higher qty than the other orders? Then it would be misleading to show an average fill rate of 90% because on the order that counted, you missed all the sales.

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: Basically I want to do this but based on the summary data only. (NVL({quantitycommitted},0)+NVL({quantityshiprecv},0))/NULLIF({quantity},0)

I don't know if it's possible. With the above and with the AVERAGE function, it's giving me the average of the individual order fill rates. I want the aggregate fill rate instead. If there are 10 orders and 9 filled at 90%, 1 at 0%, my current formula gives me 90%. But what if that 1 order had a way higher qty than the other orders?

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under your question to add that information to it. Not everyone reads all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

@Dars is correct, but I thought I'd give you a picture of what that looks like in the NetSuite UI.

[image: NetSuite UI]

It doesn't matter what fields you Group by, and you can use the Minimum, Maximum, or Average Summary Type for your Formula (Percent) field

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar logic you may use:

((sum({quantityshiprecv})/sum({quantity})) * 100)